# Put 2 columns of recycler view every row

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I would like to put 2 columns of recyclerview every row.

Right now my design is like this:
[image]

and i would like to put 2 so the scroll is not to long.

I have this view inside a fragment and I use a recyclerview adapter but I have no clue how to tell it to use its parent with, so it can fill the width of the screen. In the fragment I recive a JSON from an online database using an AsyncTask and fill in the recyclerview on the onPostExecute of the AsyncTask.

If anyone has any Idea how i can do it, I can't seem to find this anywhere

Thx!

My recyclerview Adapter:

```html
package com.example.juanfri.seguridadmainactivity;

/**
 * Created by jlira on 30/05/2017.
 */

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Juanfri on 29/05/2017.
 */

public class RecyclerAdapterSerie extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterSerie.SerieHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Serie> mSerie;
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapterSerie.SerieHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_card, viewGroup, false);
        return new SerieHolder(inflatedView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapterSerie.SerieHolder holder, int i) {
        Serie itemPhoto = mSerie.get(i);
        holder.bindPhoto(itemPhoto);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSerie.size();
    }

    public RecyclerAdapterSerie(ArrayList<Serie> serie) {
        mSerie = serie;
    }
    public static class SerieHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        //2
        private ImageView mItemImage;
        private TextView mItemDate;
        private TextView mItemDescription;
        private Serie serie;

        //3
        private static final String PHOTO_KEY = "PHOTO";

        //4
        public SerieHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            mItemImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            mItemDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_date);
            mItemDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_description);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        //5
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*Context context = itemView.getContext();
            Intent showPhotoIntent = new Intent(context, Pelicula.class);
            showPhotoIntent.putExtra(PHOTO_KEY, peli);
            context.startActivity(showPhotoIntent);*/
        }
        public void bindPhoto(Serie mserie) {
            serie = mserie;
            String Nombre = mserie.getNombreSerie();
            if(Nombre.length() >= 25)
            {
                Nombre = Nombre.substring(0,22);
                Nombre = Nombre + "...";
            }
            Picasso.with(mItemImage.getContext()).load(mserie.getPoster()).into(mItemImage);
            mItemDate.setText(Nombre);
            mItemDescription.setText(Integer.toString(mserie.getIdTMDB()));
        }
    }
}
```

My fragment (where i create the recyclerview)

```html
package com.example.juanfri.seguridadmainactivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

/**
 * Created by jlira on 06/06/2017.
 */

public class FragmentoSeriesPelis extends Fragment {

    public final String API = "5e2780b2117b40f9e4dfb96572a7bc4d";
    public final String URLFOTO ="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private ArrayList<Serie> series;
    private ArrayList<Pelicula> Pelis;
    private RecyclerAdapterSerie mAdapterSerie;
    private RecyclerAdapterPelicula mAdapterPeli;
    private int pagina;
    private String url;
    private Button CargarMas;
    private String tipo;
    private int MaxPag;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.series_pelis_layout, container, false);
        view.setTag(TAG);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        series = new ArrayList<>();
        Pelis = new ArrayList<>();
        MaxPag = 2;
        pagina = args.getInt("Page");
        url = args.getString("url");
        tipo = args.getString("Tipo");
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewSerieshoy);
        //mLinearLayoutManagerSerie = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        //recyclerViewSerie.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManagerSerie);
        //mAdapterSerie = new RecyclerAdapterSerie(seriesHoy);
        //recyclerViewSerie.setAdapter(mAdapterSerie);
        new GetSeriesHoy().execute();
        CargarMas = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCargarMas);
        CargarMas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(pagina+1<=MaxPag)
                {
                    pagina++;
                    new GetSeriesHoy().execute();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No hay mas resultados", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Series de Hoy");
    }
    private class GetSeriesHoy extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            //url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/airing_today?api_key="+API+"&language=en-US&page="+pagina;

            String aux = url+pagina;
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(aux);


            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    MaxPag = jsonObj.getInt("total_pages");
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        int IdSerie = i;
                        int idTMDB = c.getInt("id");
                        String nombreSerie;
                        String poster =URLFOTO + c.getString("poster_path");
                        if(tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("Series"))
                        {
                            nombreSerie = c.getString("name");
                            Serie nuevo = new Serie();
                            nuevo.setIdSerie(IdSerie);
                            nuevo.setNombreSerie(nombreSerie);
                            nuevo.setIdTMDB(idTMDB);
                            nuevo.setPoster(poster);
                            series.add(nuevo);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            nombreSerie = c.getString("title");
                            Pelicula nuevo = new Pelicula();
                            nuevo.setIdPelicula(IdSerie);
                            nuevo.setNombrePelicula(nombreSerie);
                            nuevo.setIdTMDB(idTMDB);
                            nuevo.setPoster(poster);
                            Pelis.add(nuevo);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            //Aqui Realizar la RecycleView BuildUp
            if(tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("Series"))
            {
                mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
                mAdapterSerie = new RecyclerAdapterSerie(series);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterSerie);
            }else
            {
                mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
                mAdapterPeli = new RecyclerAdapterPelicula(Pelis);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterPeli);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: use grid view as your row layout, and set rows = 1 and columns  = 2.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace your `LinearLayoutManager` for a `GridLayoutManager` like this:

```java
private GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager;
// ...
mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
```

Then you can use it the same way as the `LinearLayoutManager`.